# Yii2 workflow gii code generator

Tags: php, yii2, workflow, gii

i like to create the workflow using Gii in yii2.0, for that i was installed https://github.com/raoul2000/yii2-workflow-view, via my composer.

after successful installation there is no workflow generator in gii.

**code in composer.json**

```
 "raoul2000/yii2-workflow-view": "*",
```

**[image: gii screen]**

**Video**
https://vimeo.com/48693938

share your idea to resolve my problem.

Thanks in advance for your idea.

Comment: i think you understand wrongly, i update my question with video link, kindly go through with that for your better understanding

Answer (score 0):

> A Widget to display workflows created with yii2-workflow

Have you installed the actual workflow widget? https://github.com/raoul2000/yii2-workflow

Comment: Yes i have installed this above extension via composer, but i don't what i will need to next. (i mean we manually write the getDefinition() or the system itself will help us for that).